# 5x5 Table's tranformations until we find a loop

Tags: pattern

[image]

The diagram above transforming a 5x5 table into another 5x5 table. 
The transformation continues until we find a loop.
Find the rule of this transformation diagram.

Comment: Does a loop exist that contains more than two distinct numbers? More than three?

Comment: @McFry Yes, up to 4 distict numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next step, each number becomes

> the number of unique numbers in the eight squares surrounding it.